# Trusted applet security warning (yes/no) dialog not appearing in Ubuntu 8.10 and firefox

Tags: java, firefox, applet

Has anyone ever had this happen? It appears to lock the browser up until I force quit, and I have a user whose setup can reliably reproduce this, which worries me. Thoughts?

Comment: `jps` and `jstack` to see where it is stuck?

Comment: I'd guess it is appearing, just not on screen. Have you checked the other desktops? Have you tried minimizing / moving windows to make sure it's not hidden?

Comment: Nope, this is definitely still not resolved. I only get this behavior with OpenJDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dynamically embed the applet, openjdk and all linux will break. You have to embed the applet on the rendering of a page; there's no getting around this.

I used an iframe to resolve this issue while still maintaining an AJAX feel.